# How can i get the HEX color from my gradient container widget

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following gradient color

```
  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Colors.blue[400]!,
              Colors.black38,
            ]
        )
    ),
  ),
```

Now i need to get it's HEX code

for example using google color picker i can get `#0d0900` for a black color .

How could i get the same from my previous widget color ?

Comment: you want to use hexadecimal color right ?

Comment: Which goal are you trying to achieve?by using HexaDecimal

Comment: the goal is i need to get that hex to copy it to my splash screen property in .yml file . it is hard for me to get it manually from google color picker .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this function

```
String colorToHex(Color color) {
  String hex = color.value.toRadixString(16).padLeft(8, '0');
  return "#" + hex.substring(2, 8);
}
```

---

**How this work to get colors from gradient**

> In this example, a `LinearGradient` with `red` and `yellow` as its colors is created and assigned to the `gradient` variable. The colors property of the `LinearGradient` is then assigned to the `gradientColors` list.

> The map function is used to convert each color in the `gradientColors` list to its hexadecimal representation using the `colorToHex` function, and the result is assigned to the `hexColors` list.

```
LinearGradient gradient = LinearGradient(
    colors: [Colors.red, Colors.yellow],
  );

  late List<Color> gradientColors = gradient.colors;
  late List<String> hexColors =
      gradientColors.map((color) => colorToHex(color)).toList();
```

There are `Container` and `Text` Widgets in the body of `Scaffold`

```
              Container(
                width: 200.0,
                height: 100.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: gradient,
                ),
              ),
              Text("$hexColors"),
```

Comment: red.toHex() can't work

Comment: but how we can get colors from gradient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251639/discussion-between-mobin-ansar-and-horiz).

Comment: Check now. updated the answer for "get colors from gradient"

Comment: thanks it is work but does it possible if we want to get only one HEX code for both colors red and yellow ? .. for example one hex code collecting two color as a mix ? so i can use this mix whenever i want as one hex code